# Implement plain text in Dial tag of TWIML VOICE

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Follow https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial, I see that we can choose 2 options:

- **Option 1:** use plain text in **Dial** tag
- **Option 2:** use nested **Number** tag in **Dial** tag

However, I used the library java 7.17.0 to implement code and I don't know how to code follow option 1! It's always return option 2!

Maybe the sample code in Simple dial (https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial) isn't correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There is no functional difference between TwiML that directly uses a number within `<Dial>` or employs a `<Number>` element. However, I believe that you could write the Simple dial method, passing the number directly to the `Dial.Builder`, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Dial dial = new Dial.Builder("+14151234567").build();
    Say say = new Say.Builder("Goodbye").build();
    VoiceResponse response = new VoiceResponse.Builder().dial(dial)
        .say(say).build();
    try {
        System.out.println(response.toXml());
    } catch (TwiMLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```